# i need to take a part of an array and turn it into a new array

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion, byte

I have an array called data which is all of the information read from the client\server.

now in my program inorder to get the string that was sent to me I convert the bytes into string using `Encoding.ascii.getstring`

this works fine

I need to get a specific part of the data array

the part which I need is the pre translation of

```
string messageReceived = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);
messageRecived = messageRecived.Remove(0,6);
```

I need to store it as a `byte[]`

how can I get it?

###MORE INFO###

I have accesses to pre translation bytes through `data`

if it helps I can narrow down the bytes because the first 6 chars that are sent to me will not be a part of what I need.

im gettting either a rijindal key that is rsa encypted or iv that is rsa encypted or just a message that is encrypted.

also taking the first 6 will narrow down the amount of bytes ill need to read, if the first six will be "###KEY" I will read only 128, if its "###VEC" I will read 32
and if it will be anything else I will need it all

Comment: If you already have the data in a `byte[]` - are you asking how to get a sub-range of that? If so: would something like `ArraySegment<byte>` or `Memory<byte>`/`Span<byte>` work? none of those need data copying - you just tell it where to start and how long to be

Answer (score 0):

```
string messageReceived = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);
messageRecived = messageRecived.Remove(0,6);
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageRecived);
```